# yoloV3 (AlexeyAB) : rate is 0.0000

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I am using yoloV3 to train on my own training set. I have normally successfully compiled, prepared the training set, modified the config file, the .data, ...

But when training, the yolo output regarding the learning rate (i.e. rate) remains at 0 i.e.

```
 27: 1987.573730, 1807.166748 avg loss, 0.000000 rate, 2.820172 seconds, 216 images Loaded: 0.000047 seconds
```

and I don't get why ? In the config file the training rate equals to 0.001

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a warm-up. Learning rate will slowly increase from 0 to 0.001 until the number of epochs reaches `burn_in` iterations. You can find `burn_in` value in the .cfg file, it is equal to 1000 by default.